# presto: Discovery server cannot get connect

Tags: coordinates, discovery, presto

Recently I build presto with cluster mode, 1 coordinator & 1 worker, it works.
Then I repackage "presto-main-0.148.jar" without any change , and replace it to production environment, it doesn't work! Always get response with "**No worker nodes available**"

I search the Server.log and see below messages:

1. > ERROR  Discovery-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Cannot
   >   connect to discovery server for refresh (collector/general): Lookup
   >   of collector failed for
   >   ht*p://10.3.2.33:18080/v1/service/collector/general
2. > ERROR  Discovery-0 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Cannot
   >   connect to discovery server for refresh (presto/general): Lookup of
   >   presto failed for ht*p://10.3.2.33:18080/v1/service/presto/general
3. > INFO   Discovery-1 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Discovery
   >   server connect succeeded for refresh (collector/general)
4. > INFO   Discovery-2 io.airlift.discovery.client.CachingServiceSelector  Discovery
   >   server connect succeeded for refresh (presto/general)

So I guess discover server is not started,But I use command curl "h*tp://10.3.2.33:18080/v1/service/collector/general",
and get response below, and I also get coordinator status as 'ACTIVE'

```
{
    "environment": "presto_**_flt",
    "services": [
        {
            "id": "954e886d-7506-4f00-b954-eeab49209835",
            "nodeId": "4c0f2596-7e6e-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611",
            "type": "presto",
            "pool": "general",
            "location": "/4c0f2596-7e6e-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611",
            "properties": {
                "node_version": "a0e36ae",
                "coordinator": "false",
                "http": "h*tp://10.3.2.24:18080",
                "http-external": "h*tp://10.3.2.24:18080",
                "datasources": "hive,system"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "6790b522-cd17-48ef-b077-e4e8fa97e310",
            "nodeId": "4c0f2366-7e6e-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611",
            "type": "presto",
            "pool": "general",
            "location": "/4c0f2366-7e6e-11e6-ae22-56b6b6499611",
            "properties": {
                "node_version": "c34bef3-dirty",
                "coordinator": "true",
                "http": "h*tp://10.3.2.33:18080",
                "http-external": "h*tp://10.3.2.33:18080",
                "datasources": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because that you have two different node_version in these two services. 
If you are repackaging presto-main or any other component, make sure you are using the same binaries on all the nodes.